# R reading in short date instead of long date

Tags: r, date, tidyverse, lubridate

I have monthly climate data with dates stored in long format (e.g., 1/1/1950), which is how they display when opening the csv file with Excel.

However, when I read these files into R, they show a short date (e.g., 1/1/50). 
Now when I use `lubridate::mdy`, it assumes that the date is 1/1/2050. 
I could easily convert 2000s to 1900s, but these data range from 1950 to 2100. 
So some of the dates should be 2050, but some should be 1950.

Any idea why R is reading in short dates?

Note that I've set my system preferences to show as long date. 
OS info:
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
arch           x86_64
os             darwin15.6.0
system         x86_64, darwin15.6.0
status
major          3
minor          6.3
year           2020
month          02
day            29
svn rev        77875
language       R
version.string R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
nickname       Holding the Windsock

Comment: The provided link doesn't answer my question and it's not the same problem.

Comment: As I indicated, my dates are already in long format, but converted to short.

Comment: I want to read the dates in to R properly, w/o having to convert them.